# Type any <Protocol> cannot conform to Hashable

Tags: swift, generics, protocols

I'm playing with the Swift 5.7 new capabilities and I'm trying to implement some heterogeneous Sets.

I've reduced my code to this simple playground:

```
protocol Stuff: Hashable {
    var identifier: String { get }
}

struct StuffA: Stuff {
    let identifier: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
}

struct StuffB: Stuff {
    let identifier: String
    
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(identifier)
    }
}

var arrayOfStuff: Array<any Stuff> = []
arrayOfStuff.append(StuffA(identifier: "a"))
arrayOfStuff.append(StuffB(identifier: "b"))
// Works like a charm

var setOfStuff: Set<any Stuff> = Set() 
// error: Type 'any Stuff' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
setOfStuff.insert(StuffA(identifier: "a"))
setOfStuff.insert(StuffB(identifier: "b"))
```

The first try with `Array<any Stuff>` shows `any` can be used with a protocol to specify a generic constraint.

The second try fails because swift cannot checks the Hashable conformance. I know that `Stuff` does **not** conforms to Hashable, it only *inherits* from. But how do you tell the compiler that `any Stuff` will conform?

Comment: You might be misunderstanding the point of `any`. It doesn't introduce any new linguistic rules. Your code would work exactly the same way if you deleted `any`. It would work the same way if this were Swift 4. It has always been possible to make an array of protocol and it has never been possible to make a set of protocol. So Swift 5.7 and `any` are red herrings here.

Comment: Also what's the purpose of the `func hash` calls? You're not doing anything different from what the synthesized method does when you declare these struct as Hashable.

Comment: Anyway my point is:  "heterogeneous Sets" are no more possible now than they were before. You would need _type erasure_ for that. `any` is not a magic type eraser. It just means "This is the name of a protocol but what actually needs to go here is some concrete type that _conforms_ to this protocol." Which is what a protocol name in this position has _always_ meant.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

But `any` can solve some previously invalid code. For example, `Array<Hashable>` wasn't valid before. Now `Array<any Hashable>` does compile. That's exactly why I need `any` in my previous code.

Comment: But I understand the main point: "heterogeneous Sets" are still not possible

Comment: " For example, `Array<Hashable>` wasn't valid before" You're confusing apples with elephants. `Array<any Hashable>` is now legal, not because of `any`, but because it is now permitted to use a _generic protocol_ directly as a type. That part is indeed new. But again, `any` is a red herring here (though you are, of course, required to _say_ it). But, I repeat, in general `Array<SomeProtocol>` was always legal and `Set<SomeProtocol>` was not, and your code does not introduce anything new or surprising in this regard.

Comment: One final point: if you think this is a bug — that is, if you think it _should_ now be legal to say `Set<any SomeProtocol>` provided SomeProtocol is known to inherit from Hashable — then file a bug!

Comment: Ok, you're right, I shouldn't have say: "`any` can solve some previously invalid code". 
Off the record, do *you* think heterogeneous Sets should be legal?

Comment: I don't see how they can be. A Set completely depends on everybody having the same hashability / equatability rules. So it isn't enough that everybody be hashable; they would all need to be hashable in _exactly the same way_. But there's no linguistic expression for that concept.

Comment: In your example, for instance, it's true that your structs adopt a protocol that is Hashable, but how can the compiler know that one of them doesn't add _another_ property, and another of them adds a _different_ property, and now where's your Equatable / Hashable gone? It's impossible at that point

Comment: Yeah, you must be right. Thanks for this interesting discussion.