# Swift: Type 'any SomeProtocol' cannot conform to 'Hashable'

Tags: swift

Here is my code:

```
protocol SomeProtocol{
    associatedtype T
    var v: T{get set}
    var uuid: String {get set}
}

struct S1:SomeProtocol{
    var v: Int
    var uuid: String = "S1"
}

//struct S2:SomeProtocol{
//    var v: String
//    var uuid: String = "S2"
//}


var a:[any SomeProtocol] = []

a.append(S1(v: 10))
a.append(S1(v: 15))
//a.append(S2(v: "hello"))

var b = Set(a)
//Type 'any SomeProtocol' cannot conform to 'Hashable'
```

I am new to Swift, and I am wonder how to make 'any Protocol' which uses associatedtype conform to some other protocols(such as Hashable, Equitable).

Thanks!!

Comment: You cannot. Protocol do not themselves conform to protocols. You will need to redesign whatever you are building.

Comment: For another long discussion on this (via comments rather than an answer), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74067657/type-any-protocol-cannot-conform-to-hashable